# Unable to login with signup loginuser and password?

Tags: django

I'm new to django. I created a signup from from which data will be saved in the database at the time of login. It shows:

> Please enter a correct username and password.

Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

views.py:

```
def register(request):

registered = False
if request.method == 'POST':
form = signupform(request.POST,request.FILES)
  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    if 'photo' in request.FILES:
        form.picture = request.FILES['photo']
        form.save()
    return redirect("/accounts/login")
    registered = True
  else:
    print(form.errors)
else:
   form=signupform()
return render(request,'testApp/singup.html',{'registered': 
registered,'form':form})


def user_login(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
       if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Your 3010 account is disabled.")
 else:
    print("Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username,password))
    return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")

else:
return render(request, 'testapp/login.html', {})
```

Comment: You probably aren't hashing the password properly. You need to do something like `instance.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])`. If you're still stuck, then add `signupform` to your question.

Comment: where it will place instance.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])

Comment: You might be able to call `set_password` inside the form's save() method. If not, you could put change `form.save()` to `instance = form.save()`, then add `instance.set_password(...)` and `instance.save()` after that.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to manipulate your form instance, you need to "false save" your form before you make any changes to it.

You can do this via form = form.save(commit=False), that way you create a mutable instance of your form, which you can use to save your form data later after doing other manipulations or updating.

Also, you save the form instance after you have done all the manipulations.

```
def register(request):

registered = False
if request.method == 'POST':
form = signupform(request.POST,request.FILES)
signup_form = form.save(commit=False)
  if signup_form.is_valid():
    if 'photo' in request.FILES:
        signup_form.picture = request.FILES['photo']
        signup_form.save()
    return redirect("/accounts/login")
    registered = True
  else:
    print(form.errors)
else:
   form=signupform()
return render(request,'testApp/singup.html',{'registered': 
registered,'form':form})
```